# Updating Javascript literal on the page using asynchronous function

Tags: jquery

On my JSP page, I defined some javascript with a variable that get value from my controller model:

```
<!-- checkout.jsp excerpt -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = {}; 
form.checkout = {
                 "firstName" : ${checkoutForm.firstName}, // John 
                 "lastName": ${checkoutForm.lastName}     // Doe
                }; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=SOME_DOMAIN/static/js/checkout.js"></script>
```

On the same page, I have included a js file(checkout.js), which will popup a form to change those value on the page.

```
// Somewhere in "checkout.js"
var billingStr = form.checkout.firstName + ' ' +  form.checkout.lastName;

$("#billing-info-Modal").find(".modal-footer").find(".btn-primary").click(function(e){
    var formBody =  $("#billing-checkoutForm");
    // 3. update the js literal object on the page
    // alert(billingStr); result John Doe 
    form.checkout.firstName =  $(formBody).find("#billing-firstname").val(); // Peter
    form.checkout.lastName = $(formBody).find("#billing-lastname").val();    // Grimes
    // alert(form.checkout.firstName + ' ' + form.checkout.lastName); // Peter Grimes
    // alert(billingStr); result John Doe still!!

    // 4. update Billing address section
     $('#billingAddress').find('p').html(billingStr);
     // 5. close the modal
     $("#billing-info-Modal").modal('hide'); 
     e.preventDefault(); 
 });
```

Here is the excerpt of my modal form:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="billing-info-Modal">
<table id="billingTable">
            <tr class="required">
                <td><label for="billing-firstname">First Name <span>*</span></label></td>
                <td><form:input id="billing-firstname"
                        path="bFirstName" cssClass="textField" /> <form:errors
                        path="bFirstName" cssClass="errors" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="required">
                <td><label for="billing-lastname">Last Name <span>*</span></label></td>
                <td><form:input id="billing-lastname"
                        path="bLastName" cssClass="textField" /> <form:errors
                        path="bLastName" cssClass="errors" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
   </div>
```

The basic functionality of the page:

1. I would append a p tag with the form literal on page load
2. user will click on a button that popup a modal with a form that they can change firstname and lastname.
3. When user click "Save changes" on the modal, set form.checkout.firstName and form.checkout.lastName with the new values. I intend to use form.checkout as object to be submitted later on. So the accuracy are important.
4. I would like to update the p tag with the updated firstname and lastname
5. close the modal.

Maybe I am confused. I thought I can update a js literal object by setting it's field like so form.checkout.firstName = "something". Am I wrong about that? I can see that the variable inside my function is changing, but it doesn't affect the one in the outside. I thought that once a variable declared as var in a page has the global scope. Thus it can be manipulated anywhere in the page. Am I wrong about that too?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable:

```
var billingStr = form.checkout.firstName + ' ' +  form.checkout.lastName;
```

is being assigned a string equal to the first and last names *as they are when that line is executed*. It does not get automatically updated if/when those `form.checkout` properties are changed. So as shown by the alerts that you have commented:

```
alert(form.checkout.firstName + ' ' + form.checkout.lastName); // Peter Grimes
alert(billingStr); result John Doe still!!
```

The `form.checkout.firstName` and `.lastName` properties *have* changed, but this doesn't result in a change to `billingStr` - if you want `billingStr` to take a new value you have to set it again.

> *"I thought that once a variable declared as var in a page has the global scope. Thus it can be manipulated anywhere in the page."*

That is correct. It's just you haven't changed the variable that you are trying to use.

Some notes unrelated to your actual problem:

Having declared `formBody = $("#billing-checkoutForm")`, `formBody` references a jQuery object and you can then call jQuery methods on it directly like `formBody.find(...)` or `formBody.anyJqueryMethod()` - you don't need to say `$(formBody).find(...)`.

Also `$(formBody).find("#billing-firstname")` is unnecessarily complicated: you are selecting #billing-firstname by id and id should be unique - that is, you should not ever have more than one element on the page with the same id - so you can simply say `$("#billing-firstname")`.

And a terminology thing: you can't update an object *literal*, but you can update the object that was created from the literal.